# Compute the Area of Triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In $\Delta ABC , m \angle A=30$.$BC^2 = 16 (10-3\sqrt3)$ .
$AC:AB = 1:3$.
Compute the area of $\Delta ABC$

Comment: What is m? Might help if you explain a bit more. Plus drawing a picture might help you to solve it yourself

Comment: 'm' is measure of $\angle A$

Comment: Then basic trig functions and pythagoras should help along with a diagram

Comment: Yes , but I cant seem to figure out where and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Use the cosine rule to find $BC^2$.
2. Substitute $AB=3AC$ into the equation to find $AC$, then $AB$.
3. The area is: $S=\frac12\cdot AC\cdot AB\cdot \sin30^\circ$.